# Asus Maximus IV 1 long 3 short beep? Please help

Tags: memory

Hey I get this error when booting the computer I just built I searched Google and it said the error is for memory? The memory I'm using is Corsair Memory Vengeance 16GB DDR3 1600 MHz CAS 9 XMP Dual Channel Desktop is this compatible? There are 4 sticks so I don't see how it can all be faulty? I tried them separate but I get the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to all be faulty. One bad stick would cause an error like this. Take out all of the sticks except one and attempt to boot. If it works, shut down and add another stick and continue until you find the bad stick. If the first stick fails, try another one and see if it works.

You need to try this method to determine if it is in fact a single bad stick, multiple bad sticks, no bad sticks, or another problem all together.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this.

Needed two PCI-E cables into the GPU, not one.